# How to Create and Import a Custom Module in Python

Tags: python-3.x

How can I save the following function in one python file, and then use it in another?

**Function in File A**

```
def basic(x):
    print(x)
```

**Statement in File B**:

```
basic("some string")
```

Comment: `import` it? Have you tried reading a tutorial?

Comment: i have but i got confused. thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A. Create a folder which will contain all of your modules. As an example, lets use 'MyModules'

[image: Create_Directory]

B. Within the folder, save your classes in a py file. You can have more nesting than I'll demonstrate, but for simplicity we will not nest folders in this example.

[image: Classes]

[image]

C. Create another python file in the same directory named `__init__.py`. Note there are 2 underscores before and after 'init'.  Within that file, import the file you need.

The syntax should be 'from FOLDERNAME import FILENAME'

[image: Init Import]

[image: Init Location]

D. Now, from a new python file, you can import your custom classes. Note, if your package isn't recognized, you may need to change the path you're running the file from.

[image: import]

**RESULT**

[image: RESULT]

Comment: Could you please fix the pictures and edit this using the help text to the right?