# Is it circular import when using absolute import and __init__.py

Tags: python, python-import

I have the following file structure, each with at most one line of code (shown below):

```
a
├── b
│   ├── c.py          import a.b.d as d
│   ├── d.py
│   └── __init__.py   from a.b.c import *
├── __init__.py
└── main.py           import a.b as b
```

By running `python -m a.main`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/tmp/test/a/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import a.b as b
  File "a/b/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from a.b.c import *
  File "a/b/c.py", line 1, in <module>
    import a.b.d as d
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'b'
```

I am not sure if this is caused by circular import. If I change `import a.b.d as d` to `from a.b import d`, there is no error any more.

Comment: from `b.py` you should be able to just `import c` no?

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oTh1CXRaQ0) might be quite useful for handling imports, although a bit long.

Comment: @peter I have another post which covers creating and importing custom modules.  If it helps you, please upvote.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37072773/how-to-create-and-import-a-custom-module-in-python/37074372#37074372

Comment: How do you execute this scripts? Ive recreted the situation and imported a module. In my case it worked quite ok.

Comment: @Buyuk I am sorry for the previous incorrect question description. It has been modified now.

Comment: @peter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229580/python-importing-a-sub-package-or-sub-module

Comment: PS. In the future, you can remove old version of the question, it should still be visible in the edit history in case anyone wanted to see it.

Comment: @Buyuk I guess your link is not relevant because I have only used absolute import here? I have no idea how is `import a.b.d as d` different from `from a.b import d`.

Comment: @quapka Great video! I watched it through, but still had no answer to my question :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AttributeError` is caused by the `as` in the import statement in file `c.py`.

The whole process is like:

1. `main.py` created module `a`, added it to `sys.modules` and initialized it;
2. `main.py` created module `a.b`, added it to `sys.modules` and began to execute its code;
3. `b/__init__.py` (`a` and `a.b` are already in `sys.modules`) created module `a.b.c`, added it to `sys.modules` and begin to execute its code;
4. `b/c.py` created module `a.b.d`, added it to `sys.modules`, executed its code, added it as an attribute 'd' of module `a.b`, then tried but failed to bind `a.b.d` to name `d`. The problem is that module `a.b` was not done initializing yet, so the attribute 'b' was not in module `a`.

**WHY**

To understand this, you should know that an import statement does two things (in both [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/import.html) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/import.html)).

1. Find a module or modules, and initialize it or them if necessary;
2. Define a name in the local namespace and bind it to a certain module.

**Module Finding**

The former one calls the `__import__` hook, which loads the module and initializes it. In Python 2 the hook is [`imputil.ImportManager._import_hook`](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/imputil.py) by default, and it works like this.

1. Check if the module is in `sys.modules`;
2. If not, find the module and get its code;
3. Create the module and add it to `sys.modules`;
4. Run the code within the module's namespace;
5. Return the module.

If the statement is like `import a.b.c`, the module finding process will recursively find module `a`, `a.b`, `a.b.c`, and keep track of them in `sys.modules`. If module `a.b` is returned, it is set as an attribute 'b' of module `a`. Finally, the module finding process will return the top module `a`.

If the statement is like `from a.b import c,d`, the outcome is a little different. In this case the bottom module (i.e. module `a.b`) will be returned.

**Name Binding**

If you use an `import [module]` statement, the name of the top module will be bound to the return value (which is the top module).

If you use an `import [module] as [name]` statement, then `[name]` will be bound to the bottom module (by accessing the attributes of the top module).

If you use an `from [module] import [identifier]`, then the name of the bottom module will be bind to the return value (which in `from import` statement is the bottom module).

```
Example
import a.b.c          # a <- <module 'a'>
import a.b.c as c     # c <- <module 'a'>.b.c
from a.b import c     # c <- <module 'a.b'>.c
```

In your question, the import statement in `c.py` occurs when module `a.b` is half initialized and is not yet registered in module `a`'s attributes. So `import as` will encounter a problem when binding `a.b.c` to `c`. However, since module `a.b` is already registered in `sys.modules`, using `from import` will not encounter such a problem.