# How to gather information for server monitor in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I did program in tkinter. So far I succeeded to do frontend. How to grab information to my clon server monitor? This is just screenshot but in tkinter I did excact copy of this.
[image]

Comment: Well if you did, it means you accomplish it. What is your question then? Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I didnt do backend it's only frontend

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897393/simple-server-client-monitoring-tool-through-sockets-in-python

Comment: I don't know how to start with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for it like this:

1. write your code to [gather the information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37897672/13629335) in another script.
2. use [threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63414254/tkinter-gui-i-o-threading-when-to-use-queues-when-events/63416839#63416839) to run this script in your [GUI-script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37074372/13629335).
3. Use a [queue.Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48862213/13629335) to share the informations in your scripts.